# Synchronize local compact edition db to remote sql db

Tags: c#, sql-server, wpf, database, synchronization

I have a scenario where my windows form app runs locally using `.sdf` database file as datasource. A database with the same schema also exists live. The application will work offline. But it needs to sync with the remote database, whenever the system is connected to the internet *(or I can trigger synchronization manually when I need to)*. I have been through few articles/post like [THIS](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/2190.tutorial-synchronizing-sql-server-and-sql-server-compact-sync-framework.aspx), but found confusing and could not understand if this fits my scenario.

I need to know:

- Is it even practical/possible?
- I understand, handling `PK` and `FK` is going to be the big challenge at the end, is there any third party tool available to make things simple in my scenario?

Any help with little sample would be appreciated. You can guide me to some link that may solve my problem.

Other info:

- VS 2013
- SQL Server 2012
- Entity Framework
- WPF App

Comment: How much data do you have in your compact db?

Comment: @zaitsman It has 45 tables, and roughly 50 operations per table per day *(on avg)*

Comment: Since you don't specify the data type or size (e.g. are you saving hundreds of megabytes varbinary), why dont you simply ship the data via http or similar transport?

Comment: @zaitsman i dont have any idea about that. Can you guide me to some useful link/tutorial for that? Does it realy fit in my scenario? *(i.e, transport/sync data only when connected to internet)* and what about *PK* n *FK*?

Comment: em you'd build a service on one end and a client on the other. if the relationship between data is important to you then submit data from the parent nodes down...